# Samba does not allow group of file more permissions than the owner

Tags: samba, lubuntu

I have got a samba server and it was all working fine until I changed some of the permissions of my files. They were 777 (which worked) but now I have changed them to 570 for security reasons. The owner of the files is www-data and the group is webEditor.

John is in the webEditor group (which should have full permission over the files). And it works... in the command line. Samba does not give John write permission.

For some reason, changing the permissions of the file to 775, giving the owner write permission as well, samba gives John write permission over the files. Is this because samba only allows groups to have less permissions than the users?

My smb.conf is:

```
[www]
path = /var/www/
valid users = @webEditor
read only = no
```

PS - Yes, I have set the permissions recursively and I do need www-data to be the owner of the file.

Thanks in advance